# Why is 'publisher' not a mandatory field for books in biblatex in contrast to bibtex?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

The [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf#page=14) of bibtex states that 'Publisher' is a mandatory field for a book entry.
The bibliography manager jabref and bibdesk follow this rule.

In the case of biblatex the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#page=7)
says that it isn't.

I am not an expert in official citation policies, however, IMHO publisher should be mandatory. Why does biblatex differ from bibtex/jabref/bibdesk?

Related questions:

- [How to validate (check) a biblatex .bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173621/how-to-validate-check-a-biblatex-bib-file)
- [How can one validate a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128989/how-can-one-validate-a-bib-file)

Comment: Why should the publisher be mandatory? You can easily find a book with its title/author/year...

Comment: There may be books for which the "publisher" is either unknown or irrelevant, e.g., self-published books. Just out of curiosity: *Why do you care* whether the `publisher` field is declared to be mandatory or optional? It's not as if biblatex will discard the `publisher` field if it's non-empty...

Comment: Well, apparently bibtex suggests that these should be mandatory and warns the user about it. Journal citation style guides show only examples with the publisher. My intention is to use biber with validate-datamodel to check if I have incomplete bib entries. This does happen.

Comment: Regarding unknown publisher or if a book is only published by yourself: I would highly appreciate it if a reference list would tell me about it. This is a clear indication that the book might be hard to get . This is valuable information.

Comment: Regarding identifying a book by author, title and year: this also applies to journal articles (except people submit the same work more than once), but the journal name is mandatory for articles.

Comment: The standard `biblatex` styles do not need `publisher` to print a citation or the bibliography. So it's technical optional. You can easily define your own style that adds tests for empty field that should be mandatory in your opinion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's important to remember that 'required' for a classical BibTeX style means broadly 'The output might look odd without this field': BibTeX is not really trying to do data validation!

When Philipp Lehman wrote `biblatex` he looked carefully at what was and wasn't common in bibliographies and tried to make a sensible set of standard styles. He also set up `biblatex` so that in the main missing fields (even 'required' ones) don't give badly formatted output, although from the point of view of looking up references it may be sub-optimal. The 'required' fields are therefore best viewed as a suggestion for the minimum set that are needed to have any kind of 'reasonable' output, and are deliberately kept to as small a set as possible.

If you wish to do data validation, you really need to look at a range of issues not limited to the simple question of 'which fields have some content'.

Comment: I hope this covers some of the issues: it's as much a question of the ideas as anything technical.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also the comment by @Schweinebacke was helpful to understand the motivation by biblatex how to choose mandatory fields.

Comment: I think it was interesting that Biblatex earlier let  "incollection", "inproceedings" and "proceedings" have a required field "editor", even though that was optional for the same types in BibTeX. Of course the standard classes handles works without this fine, and it was made optional after I [reported it](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/199). Having the set being kept as small as possible is good!